# Automated Instagram Statistics Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, instagram

I'm creating a Google Script that automatically tracks the followers numbers of several accounts at the same time, and every hour records a row in my spreadsheet with: "date", "the time", "account1 followers #", "account2 followers #", "account3 followers #"...

I can manage when I directly input the accounts into the code, like this:

```
var sheetName = "Data - Instagram";
var instagramAccountName = "account1";
var instagramAccountName1 = "account2";
var instagramAccountName2 = "account3";

function insertData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(this.sheetName);
  sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM"), getInstagramFollowerCount(this.instagramAccountName), getInstagramFollowerCount(this.instagramAccountName1), getInstagramFollowerCount(this.instagramAccountName2)]);  
 };

function getInstagramFollowerCount(username) {
  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(response).user.followed_by.count;
}
```

Which is inefficient, specially when I want to check 40 accounts; so the problems start when I import the accounts names directly from the Spreadsheet into an array...

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet_id"); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data - Accounts');
var Accounts = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();


function insertFollowers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Followers - Data');
  sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM"), Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-05", "HH:mm"), FollowerCount(this.Accounts)]); 
};

function FollowerCount(usernames) {

  for (var i = 0; i < Accounts.length; i++) {
      var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + usernames[i] + "/?__a=1";
      var response = [];
      response[i] = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      var array = [];
      array[i] = JSON.parse(response[i]).user.followed_by.count;
     }
  return array
}
```

I don't get errors, but the only thing I get in my cells are the "Date", "Time" and "[Ljava.lang.Object;@e8c627c" in the next cells. I know the problem is of course on how I read, write and export arrays.

I'm sorry for the rookie array mistakes, I'm a decent coder, but I'm just beginning learning Javascript.

EDIT 1 - Thank you for your quick responses; I've made some progress:

```
function FollowerCount(usernames) {
   var array = [];
   var response = [];
   var number = Accounts.length;


  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + usernames[i] + "/?__a=1";
      response[i] = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      array[i] = JSON.parse(response[i]).user.followed_by.count;
     }
  return array
}
```

This now returns a 1D array with all the values I need:

[8498, 19120, 4030, ...]

Now, the thing is how to write them on the ss, along with the date and hour.

Comment: How about a modification from ``FollowerCount(this.Accounts)`` to ``JSON.stringify(FollowerCount(this.Accounts))``. ``[Ljava.lang.Object`` means an object which is JSON and Array at Google Apps Script. By the way, there are ``var array = [];`` and ``array[i]=...`` in the same loop. So it seems that the retrieved data is in only last element of ``array``. If you want to retrieve all data in an array, please put ``var array = [];`` to outside of the loop.

Comment: With your comments I made a lot of progress.

Comment: Welcome. I'm happy I was helpful for you. Thank you, too.